# Nil optional unwrap error when firebase value gets set in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uicollectionviewcell

I call firebase database to retrieve names of locations. I store the data in an array of dictionaries, then populate collectionView cells with the data from the array. when the collection view cell is selected, I segue to another view controller and pass the data to a collectionViewCell inside the view controller.

The console prints the correct values, but when I set a UILabel text equal to the value, the compiler throw a nil optional unwrap error.

Passing the data to the view controller in didSelectItemAt:
[image]

Setting a value to a UILabel text:
[image]

Console prints the value:
[image]

Am I passing the data incorrectly?
Im not sure why the console is printing the value, but compiler throws an error. Any insight as to why this happens, and how to correct this is very appreciated.

EDIT: ozzieozumo was correct, I was incorrectly instantiating my cell class. I was creating a new instance of my cell, but had no connection to storyboard, which led to my label being nil.

SOLUTION: I edited my segue method to take my dictionary as a parameter. instead of instantiating the CollectionViewCell in the method, I instantiated the CollectionViewController and passed my dictionary to the CollectionViewController. In the Controller under cellForItemAt, I set pass the data to the cell.

Comment: The only possibility is that `locationNameLabel` is `nil` when you attempt to give it a `text` value. Either instantiate the label earlier, update the property later, or make sure you've properly created an outlet for the label from Interface Builder.

Comment: The locationNameLabel might be nil and you're trying to give text to it. Please ensure that the label is properly linked to IB. Check by right clicking in Label, whether it's connected to your view controller or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment statement fails because the left hand side is nil, not the right hand side.

Your outlet is nil because of the way you are instantiating the cell instance.

`let detailImageCell = LocationDetailImagesCell()`

That will create a new instance of your cell but that instance has nothing to do with your storyboards/xibs, and so the outlets will be uninitialized.

That is your immediate problem here.

Comment: I see. What would be the proper way to instantiate? If I make the label programmatically, there would be no connection to storyboard/xibs. Ive tried creating this programatically. the error is gone, but the label still does not update. Thanks!

Comment: Conceptually, your segue should be passing the required data to the destination view controller, which should instantiate its own views and then display the data from viewDidLoad.  It seems to me that you are trying to pass a view object, rather than just passing the data. Its difficult to offer further advice without seeing more of the code.

Comment: No, you have already given me a great enough hint! Thank you!

Comment: Yes you were correct, I needed to pass data via the segue. Thank you for your help!